# How can I speed up Ant Compilation in FDT / Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, ant, compilation, mxmlc, fdt

Is there any way to speed up MXMLC compiles using Flextasks in Ant in Eclipse. Compared to FDT and Flex Builder's in-built compilation, it is painfully slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HellFire Compiler Daemon (http://bytecode-workshop.com/) comes with a set of ant tasks that build Flex applications much faster with HFCD.

http://stopcoding.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/hfcd-ant-tasks-outperform-adobe-flex-ant-tasks/

Answer (score 3):

Try adding ***incremental="true"*** to your `<mxmlc />` tag. That flag is on by default in Flex Builder, and stops the compiler from starting over each time.